# How to wrap an unquoted address in a file with bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed, scripting

In my bash script, I have been trying unsuccessfully to get a file address that is not wrapped in double quotes for some reason to be wrapped in double quotes so my script and read the address as one token and input that address into an array element housing addresses. i.e I want

```
42 Example Lane Bash City Bashland
```

to become

```
"42 Example Lane Bash City Bashland"
```

so I can assign it to ARRAY[4] in my script. Any ideas on how to get double quotes wrapped around the address that do not have double quotes? Its in a .txt file line structure as follows:

```
FirstName LastName dd/mm/yyyy Address
```

How do I wrap double quotes around the addresses that does not have them? I tried sed but I seem to be hitting a roadblock trying to get unquoted addresses quoted for processing as a single token in the script.

Comment: It sounds like you're writing a shell script to manipulate text. If so don't do that as it's not what a shell is for. A shell is for manipulating files/processes and sequencing calls to tools. The standard, general-purpose UNIX tool to manipulate text is awk. So, if you are manipulating text with a UNIX shell then the shell part should just be a call to awk. Get the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins to learn awk and see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice for more info on why not shell.

Comment: Hi Ed, thanks for the feedback. I'm basically reading uncleansed data from an input file and distributing the results in a created output file structure (by the script) in line with output specifications. The manipulation issue I have here is one of validation of address, the read command is very handy but if the address (multiple word attribute) is not wrapped in quotes and thus treated as a single token, first word addresses are pulled from the address that is not wrapped in quotes. Thats my current problem at this stage in development. Cheers for the tip on awk bro!!.. I shall explore!!..

Comment: Thanks all for your inputs, I've learned loads from the solutions and how they are applicable to my partly built script. I'm gonna go with the regex as its most aligned with the flow of my script as SLePort has suggested!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ sed 's/\(.*[0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{4\} \)\([^"]\)\(.*\)\([^"]\)$/\1"\2\3\4"/' <<< "John Doe 04/12/1960 42 Example Lane, Bash City, Bashland"  
John Doe 04/12/1960 "42 Example Lane, Bash City, Bashland"
```

All characters up to and after the date are captured.  Using backreferences, captured groups are output with surrounding `"`.

To edit a file *in place*, add the `-i` flag to sed:

```
sed 's/\(.*[0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{2\}\/[0-9]\{4\} \)\([^"]\)\(.*\)\([^"]\)$/\1"\2\3\4"/' file.txt
```

**Edit:**

Same result and maybe a bit more readable with Extended Regular Expressions:

```
sed -E 's/(.*[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4} )([^"])(.*)([^"])$/\1"\2\3\4"/' <<< 'John Doe 04/12/1960 42 Example Lane, Bash City, Bashland'
```

Comment: Thanks bro... this regex worked for me, am recoding the extra loop into my script now to clean up the distributed outputs.

Answer (score 1):

In bash, you generally don't need (or want) quotes in your data. Quotes go *around* data, not in it. You should almost always have double-quotes around variable references, but almost never store any sort of quotes as part of the data in variables. But the details will depend on exactly what you're doing. Here's a quick example:

```
read firstName lastName date address <file.txt
# Note that if there are more space-separated "words" in the line than variables,
# `read` lumps everything into the last variable (i.e. address)
userArray=("$firstName" "$lastName" "$date" "$address")
# Double-quotes keep $address from being split into multiple array entries
echo "${userArray[0]} ${userArray[1]}'s address is:"
# Note that one set of double-quotes is enough to protect the whole string,
# even though there are multiple variable references in it.
echo "  ${userArray[3]}"
```

If you need quotes in the output, add them when outputting the data:

```
echo "Address='$address'" # Single-quotes around data
echo "Address=\"$address\"" # Double-quotes must be escaped inside other double-quotes
```

If you're looping over the file, you'd use something like this:

```
while read firstName lastName date address; do
    # do stuff with the data
done <file.txt
```

BTW, putting different kinds of data (name, date, etc) in arrays is a bit weird; usually you use arrays to store a list of values of the same type. But again, it depends on the exact situation.

Comment: Cheers Gorden.. I see where you are coming from. Problem I have is trying to get validation on the address where I read the file input by line then declare and input it onto an array. The array wont read an address in full as a single token unless its got double quotes ergo my problem and need for validation pre processing of the line read into array (elements).

Comment: @JohnMulhall: Most methods of setting an array in bash follow the rule I gave: they respect quotes around the data, but not in it. For example, if you have `raw_line='Joe Smith 11/22/33 "42 Example Lane Bash City Bashland"'`, then do `declare -a foo=($raw_line)`, you'll wind up with an array that has elements 'Joe' 'Smith' '11/22/33' '"42' 'Example' 'Lane' 'Bash' 'City', and 'Bashland"' -- since the double-quotes were *in* the variable rather than *around* it, they're just treated as part of the data, not as syntactically significant.

Comment: Got it... thanks Gordon.... the file writes are  working without quotes to the individual folder files recording individual information....

Comment: Thanks for your help on this! It's been a big help!!.. 

Answer (score 1):

Unless performance is paramount, **Bash's own `read` builtin offers a convenient solution**:

<sup>The example uses a [here-document](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/HereDocument) in lieu of a text input file; to use a file, substitute the `<<'EOF'` and all remaining lines with `< your-file.txt`).</sup>

```
while read -r first last date addr; do
    [[ $addr == \"*\" ]] || addr="\"$addr\""
    echo "first: [$first], last: [$last], date: [$date], addr: [$addr]"
done <<'EOF'
First1 Last1 dd/mm/yyyy Address one unquoted
First2 Last2 dd/mm/yyyy "Address two double-quoted"
EOF
```

This yields:

```
first: [First1], last: [Last1], date: [dd/mm/yyyy], addr: ["Address one unquoted"]
first: [First2], last: [Last2], date: [dd/mm/yyyy], addr: ["Address two double-quoted"]
```

This solution:

- takes advantage of the fact that `read` reads the *remainder* of the line into the last variable specified, if there are fewer variables than fields in the input line.
- `[[ $addr == \"*\" ]]` tests if the value read into `$addr` is already `"`-enclosed (note the need to `\`-escape the `"` chars. so as to treat them as *literals*) and, if not (`||`), replaces the value of `$addr` with itself enclosed in `"`.

---

That said, given that **double quotes are usually used as *syntactic* elements that *enclose* strings for *delimiting* rather than being *part of the strings themselves***, you may choose the opposite approach, namely to ***remove* *embedded* enclosing `"` chars. from the addresses in the input**:

```
while read -r first last date addr; do
    [[ $addr =~ \"(.*)\" ]] && addr="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    echo "first: [$first], last: [$first], date: [$first], addr: [$addr]"
done <<'EOF'
First1 Last1 dd/mm/yyyy Address one unquoted
First2 Last2 dd/mm/yyyy "Address two double-quoted"
EOF
```

This yields:

```
first: [First1], last: [First1], date: [First1], addr: [Address one unquoted]
first: [First2], last: [First2], date: [First2], addr: [Address two double-quoted]
```

As you can see, the `"` chars. surrounding the address on the 2nd input line were removed from the value stored in `$addr`.

This solution:

- uses [`=~`, Bash's regex-matching operator](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) to match addresses enclosed in *literal* double quotes (`\"(.*)\"`)
- and, if so (`&&`), redefines `$addr` to the string *between* the enclosing double quotes, via the value that the parenthesized subexpression (capture group, `(.*)`), captured (`${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`).

Answer (score 0):

`FirstName LastName dd/mm/yyyy Address`? How about double First or double LastNames? Luckelly ypu are only interested in the part after `"/yyyy "`.
When you are a newbie, start with small steps that you understand:

```
# Remove first part of string. In `sed` you can use `#`when `/` is part of your string.
echo "Mr John F Someone 11/04/2008 44 street somewhere" | sed 's#.*/.... ##'
# Put string in quotes
echo "Mr John F Someone 11/04/2008 44 street somewhere" | sed 's/.*/"&"/'
# Put string in quotes differently (for later study)
printf '"%s"\n' "$(echo "Mr John F Someone 11/04/2008 44 street somewhere")" 
# Combine two sed commands (after a pipe you can enter a newline)
echo "Mr John F Someone 11/04/2008 44 street somewhere" | 
   sed -e 's#.*/.... ##' -e 's/.*/"&"/'
# Or 
echo "Mr John F Someone 11/04/2008 44 street somewhere" | 
   sed 's#.*/.... ##;s#.*#"&"#'
# Or
echo "Mr John F Someone 11/04/2008 44 street somewhere" | 
   sed -e 's#.*/.... \(.*\)#"\1"#'
```